# PHP Data Looping in girds

Tags: php, html, css, loops

I have been trying to loop Data from a Rest , and i am able to do it without grid but with grid it just doesn't work . Here is the Source code where i am trying to loop .

**THE CODE WITH ERROR**

```
<?php
 $json = file_get_contents('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com&apiKey=5d');
 $news= ( json_decode($json, true));
 $ii = 0;
 foreach ($news["articles"] as $headling["articles"]) {?>
<div class="row"><?php
foreach ( $headling["articles"] as $i => $newsdata){?>
    <?php if($ii==0){
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="header">
                                <h4 class="title">Email Statistics</h4>
                                <p class="category">Last Campaign Performance</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <img src="<?php echo $newsdata['urlToImage'];?>" style="width:100%;" />                          <div class="footer">
                                    <div class="legend">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-info"></i> Open
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i> Bounce
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i> Unsubscribe
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="stats">
                                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Campaign sent 2 days ago
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <?php
        $ii =1 ;
    }else{
        ?>
         <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="header">
                                <h4 class="title">Users Behavior</h4>
                                <p class="category">24 Hours performance</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                            <img src="<?php echo $newsdata['urlToImage'];?>" style="width:100%;" />                          <div class="footer">

                                <div class="footer">
                                    <div class="legend">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-info"></i> Open
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i> Click
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i> Click Second Time
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="stats">
                                        <i class="fa fa-history"></i> Updated 3 minutes ago
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

        <?php
        $ii = 0;
    }
}
    ?>
    </div>              

<?php
 }


?>
```

**THE PROBLEM ?**
It is not giving me any Error, I have been try to do it with a inner loop.But it just doesn't work Here is the Screenshot. Well basically what i am thinking is its not looping the rows .
[Here it is](https://ibb.co/iojd2o)

**EDIT**

The loop inside a loop was just useless.

Comment: looks like for starters you got one extra /div in the if $ii == 0

Comment: its duplicating 10 records 10 time because of loop inside loop, what do you think why its happening, and have a look https://ibb.co/cNru8T

Comment: Firstly, you shouldnt be sharing your api key.  second, there appears to be 20 records, if you have more than 10 rows after you fix your divs, the most likely culprit is your loops. I'd start by fixing your divs to see where the actual issue is. Then use your browser to fetch the json, if there are more than Articles/2 rows its the way you are parsing the json into loops. Remove one of your loops. see what happens. like foreach ( $headling["articles"] as $i => $newsdata){?> and its corresponding closing bracket.

Comment: Thanks there was no need of inner loop , just removed the first loop and it looped the data. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a `</div>` inside the `else { ... }` part. See the pretty formatted code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="card">
   <div class="header">
      <h4 class="title">Users Behavior</h4>
      <p class="category">24 Hours performance</p>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      <img src="<?php echo $newsdata['urlToImage'];?>" style="width:100%;" />                          
      <div class="footer">
         <div class="footer">
            <div class="legend">
               <i class="fa fa-circle text-info"></i> Open
               <i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i> Click
               <i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i> Click Second Time
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="stats">
               <i class="fa fa-history"></i> Updated 3 minutes ago
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But one problem solved the other is now its duplicating every rows for 10 times